# airflow upgrade_check FERNET_KEY issue

Tags: airflow, fernet

I am running the command `airflow upgrade_check` to do the checks before migrating to `Airflow 2.0`.

I get the Fernet issue as a problem:

```
Fernet is enabled by default
The fernet mechanism is enabled by default to increase the security of the default installation.

Problems:

  1.  fernet_key in airflow.cfg must be explicitly set empty as fernet mechanism is enabledby default. This means that the apache-airflow[crypto] extra-packages are always installed.However, this requires that your operating system has libffi-dev installed.
```

In the airflow.cfg file I have the fernet_key param with a value created using:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
fernet_key= Fernet.generate_key()
print(fernet_key.decode())
```

And the problem stills there. I tried setting `fernet_key` empty such as:

```
fernet_key =
```

I have installed crypto with pip:

```
pip install apache-airflow[crypto,postgres,ssh,s3,log]=1.10.14
```

In the applying the recommendations section in this [link from Airflow doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/upgrade-check.html) they explain to create a valid `fernet_key` which is what I did.

Any other idea how can u fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue.
I had the `fernet_key` parameter in another `airflow.cfg` section. It must be in `[core]` section.